# How to create settings with dynamic dependencies?

Tags: sbt, sbt-0.13

I want a setting to depend on settings of a dynamic list of other projects (well, executed at SBT setting start up, but dynamic in the sense that it is not hard-coded).

I have `Def.dynTask` to produce a task with a dynamic dependency on other tasks.

Is there a similar way to do this for settings, i.e. produce a setting with a dynamic dependency on other settings?

---

Or perhaps I misunderstand settings. FYI, my understanding is that settings are computed once at start up; tasks are computed whenever they are requested.

Answer (score 0):

Setting is actually initialized only one per sbt session. The good explanation about that can be found [here](https://jazzy.id.au/2015/03/03/sbt-task-engine.html)

If I got your idea in right way, you can do that with TaskKeys and the `sbt.Extracted.append` method. Be careful, I have faced strange think like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251711/why-sbt-extracted-remove-the-previously-defined-taskkey-while-append-method)

Comment: Barys, right. I know that they are computed once. But I wanted to know if they could be computed based on other settings, but the exact list wasn't known at compile time.