# Why sbt.Extracted remove the previously defined TaskKey while append method?

Tags: scala, sbt

There is a suitable method in the sbt.Exctracted to add the TaskKey to the current state. Assume I have `inState: State`:

```
val key1 = TaskKey[String]("key1")
Project.extract(inState).append(Seq(key1 := "key1 value"), inState)
```

I have faced with the strange behavior when I do it twice. I got the exception in the following example:

```
val key1 = TaskKey[String]("key1")
val key2 = TaskKey[String]("key2")
val st1: State = Project.extract(inState).append(Seq(key1 := "key1 value"), inState)
val st2: State = Project.extract(st1).append(Seq(key2 := "key2 value"), st1)
Project.extract(st2).runTask(key1, st2)
```

leads to:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: */*:key1 is undefined.
```

The question is - why does it work like this? Is it possible to add several `TaskKey`s while executing the particular task by several calls to `sbt.Extracted.append`?

The example sbt project is [sbt.Extracted append-example](http://pastebin.com/zEWhcCki), to reproduce the issue just run `sbt fooCmd`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Josh Suereth** posted the [answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/sbt-dev/879dd5cc-9114-4755-8196-c78f04ec95c9%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer) to sbt-dev mail list. Quote:

> The `append` function is pretty dirty/low-level.  This is probably a bug in its implementation (or the lack of documentation), but it blows away any other appended setting when used.
>
> What you want to do, (I think) is append into the current "Session" so things will stick around and the user can remove what you've done via "sesison clear" command.
>
> Additonally, the settings you're passing are in "raw" or "fully qualified" form.  If you'd for the setting you  write to work exactly the same as it would from a build.sbt file, you need to transform it first, so the Scopes match the current project, etc.
>
> We provide a utility in sbt-server that makes it a bit easier to append settings into the current session:
>
> https://github.com/sbt/sbt-remote-control/blob/master/server/src/main/scala/sbt/server/SettingUtil.scala#L11-L29

I have tested the proposed solution and that works like a charm.