# How to modify a setting in a command and retain other session changes?

Tags: sbt

I have this simple command that changes the value of `myBoolSetting`:

```
commands += Command("mycommand") {
    state ⇒ (Space ~> Bool).?
} { (state, arg) ⇒
    val b = arg.getOrElse(true)
    Project.extract(state).append(Seq(myBoolSetting in Global := b), state)
}
```

When I change invoke it does change `myBoolSetting` but I lose any setting whose value has been changed by means of the `set command`.

```
> set myStringSetting := "new value"
> myCommand false
```

In this example, the value of `myStringSetting` has been lost and has its default value.

How can I change a setting and keep manual changed settings?

**UPDATE**:

Found related question: [Why sbt.Extracted remove the previously defined TaskKey while append method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29251711/why-sbt-extracted-remove-the-previously-defined-taskkey-while-append-method), but seems not to work in my case.

Modified code:

```
commands += Command("mycommand") {
    state ⇒ (Space ~> Bool).?
} { (state, arg) ⇒
    val b = arg.getOrElse(true)
    val session = Project.session(state)
    val state2 = Project.extract(state).append(Seq(myBoolSetting in Global := b), state)
    SessionSettings.reapply(session, state2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I might only partially answer your question.

The reason for losing `myStringSetting` new value is that `myCommand` reloads a session effectively leaving you with what you have already in build.sbt-like files and what the command itself set. You simply drop the value while reloading the session.

It is similar to doing `set scalaVersion := "2.11.7"` and `reload` afterwards. `scalaVersion` becomes the default Scala version you had in sbt configuration.

You now know why you lose the value. If you want to retain the value you'd have to save the current session `session save` and execute your command. You need to add `session save` to your command.

Comment: This answer is partial but provides a clue.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it helped a bit. Why don't you simply `session save` before calling a command? It's by design that as the session gets dropped all the temporary values will, too.

Comment: My objective is to incrementally change the session settings.

Comment: In addition `session save` does change my `build.sbt`, and it can cause git conflicts.

Comment: Ah, so you want to retain temporary session changes without saving them?

Comment: Yes, just changing session state.